# Why is my Python range loop not looping the correct number of times and resetting correctly consistently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am creating an interactive game but I am stuck on getting the loop of 'games' to work correctly.

I have asked the user for input to determine the number of loops. The variable is an integer and the only numbers accepted are 1-5 inclusive. What I am expecting is if the user enter 2 then the game loops twice (unless both characters die by way of the health declining to 0).

There are other options in the game such as resetting character health etc and then the user can go back to the battle option and again enter the number of games they want to play.

What I am finding is:

- sometimes the number of battles played matches what the user enters BUT sometimes it doesn't work (i.e. user enters 2 but it plays 4 games)
- it never works if the user enters 1 (I have tried changing the line around number_rounds != 1 to 0 but that doesn't work either

I have only pasted the relevant snippet of code in hope that someone who is more familiar with Python can spot the issue. Thanks in advance.

```py
# Defining the function to display highest battles won
def do_battle(character_list, opponent1_pos, opponent2_pos):

    # Requesting user input to select number of rounds to be played
    number_rounds = int(input('Please enter number of battle rounds: '))
    
    # While loop to validate input is a number between 1-5 inclusive
    while number_rounds < 1 or number_rounds > 5:
        print('Must be between 1-5 inclusive.')
        number_rounds = int(input('Please enter number of battle rounds: '))
    
    player1_health = character_list[opponent1_pos][-1]
    player2_health = character_list[opponent2_pos][-1]
    
    round_number = 0
    
    for i in range(number_rounds):
        while number_rounds != 1 and player1_health > 0 and player2_health > 0:
            round_number = round_number + 1
            damage1 = random.randint(0, 50)
            player1_health = max(0, player1_health - damage1)
            character = character_list[opponent1_pos]
            character[-1] = player1_health
            damage2 = random.randint(0, 50)
            player2_health = max(0, player2_health - damage2)
            character = character_list[opponent2_pos]
            character[-1] = player2_health
```

Comment: You don't need `number_rounds != 1` in your `while` condition since you're already wrapping a `for`-loop around it.

Comment: I think the condition number_rounds != 1 makes you skip a round. like @StefanFalk wrote, you don't need it

Comment: I had tried removing it and without it the loop still misbehaves but still quite sporadically but consistently never loops the amount of times entered in the number_rounds input variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> user enters 2 but it plays 4 games

The problem is your `while` loop inside the `for` loop - that is why you get more rounds than intended, because you are looping within the loop.

If I understood the intent correctly, what you want is to play *up to* `number_rounds` rounds and then stop when one of the players' health reaches zero?

In that case what you really want there is just an `if` statement.

Also, you don't need the `round_number` variable, since you have `i` from the for loop. And I don't see the point of `while number_rounds != 1` either.

My attempt at a fixed version would look like:

```py
# Defining the function to display highest battles won
def do_battle(character_list, opponent1_pos, opponent2_pos):

    # While loop to validate input is a number between 1-5 inclusive
    number_rounds = 0
    while True:
        number_rounds = int(input('Please enter number of battle rounds: '))
        if 1 <= number_rounds <= 5:
            # exit the loop if they entered a valid value
            break
        print('Must be between 1-5 inclusive.')
    
    player1_health = character_list[opponent1_pos][-1]
    player2_health = character_list[opponent2_pos][-1]
    
    for i in range(number_rounds):
        print(f"Round #{i + 1}")

        damage1 = random.randint(0, 50)
        player1_health = max(0, player1_health - damage1)
        character = character_list[opponent1_pos]
        character[-1] = player1_health

        damage2 = random.randint(0, 50)
        player2_health = max(0, player2_health - damage2)
        character = character_list[opponent2_pos]
        character[-1] = player2_health

        # exit the battle if any of the players died
        if player1_health == 0 or player2_health == 0:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you. I need round_number for a different reason (to print something else to screen). I wanted to try and code it without using break to exit the loop however can see if I use break as you have, and remove the while within the for loop, it works. I still don't quite understand why the while in the for loop messed with the i in range loop count so if anyone is able to help me better understand that I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: @JoRobbertsen yes I guessed that - there's an example of printing the round number using `i` in my code above

Comment: Ah yes I see that now (using the i the print the round number). I'll give that a try!